# How to send filters as part of Power BI Rest API's in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, powerbi, performance-testing

Have been using Power BI rest API in JMeter, GET [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/apps/{appId}/reports/{reportId}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/apps/%7BappId%7D/reports/%7BreportId%7D)  to get the report.

Need to retrive the report with filted data. So passed the filtered data as [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/apps/{appId}/reports/{reportId}?filter={$filter=Area](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/apps/%7BappId%7D/reports/%7BreportId%7D?filter=%7B$filter=Area) eq 'XYZ}

Same response is been displayed for both requests with & without filter.
How can I send the filter as part of API to get the right response.